# How to integrate Google & Facebook login Using React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook-login, google-signin

I have referred [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin)  documentation to add google-signin in my react native app, followed all the steps mentioned but could not get the result as specified in the documentation. I have imported the following statement

> import { GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton, statusCodes } from 'react-native-google-signin';

But Whenever I add this statement in my login file it gives me following error.
[image]

Comment: Can you share a piece of code?

Comment: Have you installed `prop-types`? Judging from the error message, `google-signin` seems to depend on it

Comment: Looks like it could be a missing dependecy..? Maybe try npm install or react-native link.

Comment: @PatrickHund I have already installed prop-types, But too its showing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need make some changed in your file path shown in error message

> F:\ReactProjects\SearchApp\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\src\GoogleSignin.android.js

make sure you import following two lines correctly

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 0):

install this and your problem goes away "npm install --save prop-types"